# Create a REST API to get the data from the custom table in magento 2

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, get

I create  a database table 'computergames' . Now the table display in postman by get request

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below steps to create an api to get data from your custom table

1- Create your module [Visit the link to create module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIMWb.png)

2- Create a File named **webapi.xml** at the folder vendor>module>etc>

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <!-- get customer Api -->
    <route url="/V1/get/customer/" method="GET">
        <service class="Vendor\Module\Api\GetCustomerInterface" method="getData" />
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous" />
        </resources>
    </route>
```

3- Create a file **di.xml** at vendor>module>etc> and create prefrence for your api

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Vendor\Module\Api\GetCustomerInterface" type="Vendor\Module\Model\GetCustomer" />
```

4- Create a File named **GetCustomerInterface.php** at Vendor > Module > Api

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\FME\Api;

interface GetCustomerInterface
{

    /**
     * GET for test api
     * @return object
     */

  public function getData();

}
```

5- Create your prefrence file named as **GetCustomer.php** at Vendor > Module > Model

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;
use Vendor\Module\Api\GetCustomerInterface;

class GetCustomer implements GetCustomerInterface
{

     /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */

    public function getData()
    {  
         
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of object manager
        $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $connection = $resource->getConnection();
        $tableName = $resource->getTableName('hse_mobileapp_customer');

        $select = $connection->select()
        ->from(
       ['p' => $tableName]);

       $data = $connection->fetchAll($select);

       return $data;

    }

}
```

Here is demo of this API running in postman

[image: Api in postman]

If you didn't understand anything or need further justification feel free to ask.

Comment: Just request GET and show the table . no any authentication

Comment: So you can simply change the query and modify the method getData() in GetCustomer.php ( do not need to add params in method )

Comment: please share the code . just GetCustomer.php

Comment: @RubelParvaz I have updated my code please try again

Comment: Thank You so mach